# Drawing example circuits with circuit_macros

Tags: circuits, engineering

At [Circuit_macro examples, Version 8.9.3 webpage](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/html/examples.html), example codes are shared with the outputs.
I am trying to draw transformers, especially the one on the following picture:

[image: magnetic-circuit]

Then, I copied the code of this example in order to try and undertand it.
https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/html/Windings.txt

When converting the `Windings.m4` file into `Windings.tex`, no problem occurs.
In the command prompt, I wrote the following command:

> m4 Windings.m4|dpic -g>Windings.tex

BUT, typesetting the latex file into pdf won't do. The typesetting returns a large number of errors which is difficult for me to understand.

Here are the screenshots of the error messages:

[image: error1]
[image: error2]

Comment: Are you working with MS Windows and Power Shell as command prompt? In that case, pay attention to the encoding!

Comment: Yes. I am working on a windows PC running Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by encoding though.

Comment: But are you using Power Shell as terminal or Command Prompt?

Comment: I am using the command prompt.

Comment: Could you please add the log with the errors to your question?

Comment: Mm... are you trying to compile directly `Windings.tex`?

Comment: I will add the screenshots of the errors from texmaker and I will add share the log file.

Comment: I am compiling `Windings.tex ` using a file where I call it using `\input Windings`

Comment: Please add also the main file: do you include the package `tikz`?

Comment: All of your images simply use a sine wave for the windings (or should).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that the command `\boxdims` is undefined.

You should thus also include the package `boxdims` which is part of the `circuit_macros` distribution.

To make it work, you should add the folder where you had copied the `circuit_macros` files to the TeX filename database.

Comment: Oh thank you! It solved the issue. But I don't know how you knew that it was the missing piece and that is part of the circuit_macros distribution. I could not even find a single mention of  the word `boxdims` in the Manual of `circuit_macros`.

Comment: Great! I don't know which version of the manual `CMman.pdf` you have, but in mine (version 8.5) you can find the description of `boxdims` in section 12, "Interaction with LaTeX".

Comment: My bad. Sorry about that. It is actually there. I am using the version 8.9.